# Tail pattern with context in Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

If I tail a log like this:

```
gc xxx.log -last 1 -wait | sls -patt 'Exception' -simple | % {write $_.Context.PreContext $_.Line $_.Context.PostContext}
```

it works as expected spitting out lines containing "Exception", but when I try to add some context like this:

```
gc xxx.log -last 1 -wait | sls -patt 'Exception' -simple -cont 1,2 | % {write $_.Context.PreContext $_.Line $_.Context.PostContext}
```

..it just works the same, it doesn't include any context lines. Can anyone tell me why and what I could do to get context lines like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...it just works the same, it doesn't include any context lines.

Because there is no context! You've explicitly told `Get-Content` to grab `1` last line with `-Last 1`, so `Select-String` receives only one line.

> Can anyone tell me why and what I could do to get context lines like this?

Sure, all you have to do, is increase number of lines for the `Last` parameter. Assuming that you match `1` line in regex and want `1` line before and `2` after it (`-Context 1,2`) then total amount of lines would be `1 + 1 + 2 = 4`:

```
Get-Content -Path 'xxx.log' -Tail 4 |
    Select-String -Pattern 'Exception' -SimpleMatch -Context 1,2 |
        ForEach-Object {
            $_.Context.PreContext
            $_.Line
            $_.Context.PostContext
        }
```